# Google Maps not showing on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing our websites contact us page and want to make use of Google Maps using an API key for our location.
The map show on a desktop but when the page is loaded on a mobile phone it doesn't show the map.
My code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="contact">

            <section class="mb-4">

                <div>
                    <h4 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact information</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="contact">

                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
                              <p>Address</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x"></i></a>
                              <p>Telephone</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
                              <p>email</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
                        <div id="map" class="map-item"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-7 mb-md-0 mb-5">

                        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                            <div class="messages"></div>

                            <div class="controls">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                                            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                            <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form_need">Please specify your need *</label>
                                            <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="Request quotation">Request quotation</option>
                                                <option value="Request order status">Request order status</option>
                                                <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Request copy of an invoice</option>
                                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                            <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-send" value="Send message">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p class="text-muted">
                                            <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </section>

        </div>f
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    function drawMap() {

        var LatLng = {lat: 0.000, lng: 0.000};

        var mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          fullscreenControl: false 
        }     

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            mapOptions,
            zoom: 18,
            center: LatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Here am I'
        });  

    }

</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API&callback=drawMap">
</script>
```

CSS:

```
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated what might cause this issue.
If I use an embedded iframe map it shows on a mobile phone but that is not what I want to use.

Comment: Does your map div have a size? What is the applicable CSS.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I've entered my whole code above with my CSS used for it.

Comment: The posted CSS by itself won't show a map.  The parent element also needs a size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `map` div is inside a `div` container that must have a height and width too. Please check out this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk59xf1b/). Full code below:

HTML

```
<div id="contact">
  <section class="mb-4">
    <div>
      <h4 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact information</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i>
            <p>Address</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
            <p>Telephone</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
            <p>email</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
        <div id="map" class="map-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 mb-md-0 mb-5">
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
          <div class="messages"></div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_need">Please specify your need *</label>
                  <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Request quotation">Request quotation</option>
                    <option value="Request order status">Request order status</option>
                    <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Request copy of an invoice</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                  <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-send" value="Send message">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted">
                  <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=drawMap"></script>
```

JS

```
var map;

function drawMap() {

  var LatLng = {
    lat: 0.000,
    lng: 0.000
  };

  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    fullscreenControl: false
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    mapOptions,
    zoom: 4,
    center: LatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: LatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Here am I'
  });

}
```

CSS

```
 #map {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .col-md-5 {
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
 }
```

Hope this helps!